# Travis max log size & omitting library generated log

Tags: maven, log4j, travis-ci, logback, apache-metamodel

I'm using Github (https://github.com/connecta-solutions/connecta-framework) and Travis (https://travis-ci.org/connecta-solutions/connecta-framework) to host and build an open-source project of mine, that uses Apache Metamodel as one of its dependencies.

I'm not making many unit tests, but the log generated by a specific test that uses a feature from Metamodel is gigantic, and passes the 4MB log size determined by Travis, so it quits the build with the following message:

```
The log length has exceeded the limit of 4 MB (this usually means that the test suite is raising the same exception over and over).

The job has been terminated
```

Most of the log I get are unimportant debug messages from a Comparator inside Metamodel, which usually gives the following output:

```
18:18:23.519 [main] DEBUG o.a.metamodel.util.ObjectComparator - compare(Sul,50)
18:18:23.519 [main] INFO  o.a.metamodel.util.ObjectComparator - Using ToStringComparator because no apparent better comparison method could be found
18:18:23.519 [main] DEBUG org.apache.metamodel.util.BaseObject - SUM(csv_cities.csv.vendas).hashCode()
18:18:23.519 [main] DEBUG org.apache.metamodel.util.BaseObject - obj is null, returning constant
18:18:23.519 [main] DEBUG org.apache.metamodel.util.BaseObject - obj is null, returning constant
18:18:23.519 [main] DEBUG org.apache.metamodel.util.BaseObject - obj is a regular object, returning hashCode
18:18:23.519 [main] DEBUG org.apache.metamodel.util.BaseObject - obj is a regular object, returning hashCode
18:18:23.519 [main] DEBUG org.apache.metamodel.util.BaseObject - obj is a regular object, returning hashCode
18:18:23.519 [main] DEBUG org.apache.metamodel.util.BaseObject - obj is null, returning constant
18:18:23.519 [main] DEBUG org.apache.metamodel.util.BaseObject - obj is null, returning constant
18:18:23.519 [main] DEBUG o.a.metamodel.util.EqualsBuilder - append(false)
18:18:23.519 [main] DEBUG o.a.metamodel.util.EqualsBuilder - append(true)
18:18:23.519 [main] DEBUG o.a.metamodel.util.ObjectComparator - compare(Sul,50)
18:18:23.519 [main] INFO  o.a.metamodel.util.ObjectComparator - Using ToStringComparator because no apparent better comparison method could be found
18:18:23.519 [main] DEBUG org.apache.metamodel.util.BaseObject - SUM(csv_cities.csv.vendas).hashCode()
18:18:23.519 [main] DEBUG org.apache.metamodel.util.BaseObject - obj is null, returning constant
18:18:23.519 [main] DEBUG org.apache.metamodel.util.BaseObject - obj is null, returning constant
18:18:23.519 [main] DEBUG org.apache.metamodel.util.BaseObject - obj is a regular object, returning hashCode
18:18:23.519 [main] DEBUG org.apache.metamodel.util.BaseObject - obj is a regular object, returning hashCode
18:18:23.519 [main] DEBUG org.apache.metamodel.util.BaseObject - obj is a regular object, returning hashCode
18:18:23.519 [main] DEBUG org.apache.metamodel.util.BaseObject - obj is null, returning constant
18:18:23.519 [main] DEBUG org.apache.metamodel.util.BaseObject - obj is null, returning constant
18:18:23.519 [main] DEBUG o.a.metamodel.util.EqualsBuilder - append(false)
18:18:23.519 [main] DEBUG o.a.metamodel.util.EqualsBuilder - append(true)
```

The ideal situation was that Travis somehow accepted this, as unimportant log can quickly become important when you face a problem. Anyway, I tried to reduce the log level to get only warning and errors, passing the argument for log4j to do so, like this:

```
mvn test -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=warn
```

What I later realized was that Logback was the log engine for this Metamodel feature, and I discovered that it's not possible to reduce the loglevel of Logback with a parameter like you can in Log4j. Yet I didn't find a way to remove logback and use the standard logger I'm using for the whole application, then I could control what level it tries to output a message.

Is this the last word of Travis CI? Isn't there a way to keep all the log, even if does pass the 4MB log size?

If it doesn't, how can I remove only this unimportant part of the log inside Metamodel?

Keeping the whole log in dev mode, and just omitting it on a Travis build would be perfect, but if I can't, I can omit this part of the log forever, if there's no choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to adjust the logging of specific namespace (e.g. whole `org.apache.metamodel`) via `log4j.xml` configuration file placed in `src/test/resources` of your project.

An example can be found in the metamodel codebase: https://github.com/apache/metamodel/blob/060884c17d1c5c35348d2cb675bed1c404013579/jdbc/src/test/resources/log4j.xml#L12

Comment: Funny thing, it doesn't work because my Metamodel is still using Logback, but in your link the dependency of Metamodel points only to log4j. I'll investigate which module is bringing this dependency and try to fix it...

Comment: I excluded all logger modules that could be being used instead of lo4j and now it worked. Thanks a lot :)